# How to convert a tuple object literal type and make all properties of the object literal type required

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, variadic-tuple-types

I have an tuple type that contains multiple object literal types, lets call it ***Actions*** for this example. Some of the object literal types contains optional properties. I would like to have a type that makes all properties in the object literal of the tuple type required.

```js
type ClickEvent = {
  type: 'click-event';
  name: string;
  value1?: string;
};

type PerformSearch = {
  type: 'perform-search';
  referrerPage?: string;
};

type Actions = [ClickEvent, PerformSearch]; // only two items to keep it simple for this example


type RequireAllObjectLiterals<T extends unknown[]> = ??? // how does this look like?

type RequiredActions = RequireAllObjectLiterals<Actions>;
//type should look like these at the end -> [Required<ClickEvent>, Required<PerformSearch>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mapped types on array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) produce array/types, and the type parameter you're indexing over can be interpreted as the numberlike keys of the array/tuple type.  That is, if you write `type Mapping<T> = {[I in keyof T]: F<I>}`, then assuming `T` is, say, a three element tuple type `[X,Y,Z]`, then the type parameter `I` iterates over `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"` and a new tuple type is produced like `[F<"0">, F<"1">, F<"2">]`.

So the solution here is as straightforward as:

```
type RequireAllObjectLiterals<T extends unknown[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: Required<T[I]> }
```

And you can verify that it behaves as desired:

```
type Actions = [ClickEvent, PerformSearch];
type RequiredActions = RequireAllObjectLiterals<Actions>;
// type RequiredActions = [Required<ClickEvent>, Required<PerformSearch>]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSwMYGsCiA3CA7YUC8UA3gLABQUlUokAXFAORKKoC0EWuDA3OVVNgCGAWwj0AzsABOCbAHNeFKhkFwArhACMAfgnTZC8gF9F5GtAAKEKQDMA9lOEBlCIKlIAFgWJ8q5+gyQtg7CrOKu7h48vpRSEDbWcVIWgnIQulCSMvKKJuT5ZGbg0ABKEACOaghxAIJwcADyAEYAVhBIwAAyCMDWquIAPAAqUBAAHr3YACbiUGrYKNh2AO7YANoAugB8BDHEUGsAklCyUCgQIHY2UEMb9GWV1RBTw0fbUEYF5lA1HQh22FmhDW8GQ6E4wAANFArMFHC43J4Nopvg8qnEpr9gP9Ad40U86o1Wu0uj0+nBBliceItooAPR06jFKD4jFUgFAg6s54DUGoTA4YBbaHcl6w+zwiKeLYbApAA)